# Rounding the result from CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an issue: I need to round the result of `CASE` statement. I am not sure if that is possible. If you have any ideas, let me know. I need to round the case calculation and make it round inside the table (please see the picture#2 below. I need for both OB_BILLING and RET_BILLING to have round numbers. This code needs to be used in SQL Server Management Studio.

Code

```
CASE
    WHEN s.DEIO = 'O' 
        THEN s.DERSP 
        ELSE '0'
END AS OB_BILLING,
CASE 
    WHEN s.DEIO = 'I' AND 'WALMART_CONSOLIDATE' = 'N' 
        THEN -1 * s.DERSP 
        ELSE 0
END AS RET_BILLING,
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzjmO.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ox19M.png)

Comment: use `ROUND(<value>, <no. of decimals you need>)

Comment: @SumitJaiswal this is not exactly what I need. I need to understand how to round in a case statement. What should I take in brackets to round? If I round OB_BILLING I get an error.

Comment: What's your database?

Comment: @Rezu Microsoft SQL server and I still get an error if I type SELECT ROUND (CASE
WHEN s.DEIO='O' THEN s.DERSP ELSE '0'
END AS OB_BILLING).

Comment: If you ask your question properly I mean add sample data, expected result and tag your database it would be helpful for others and it saves others times.

Comment: @Rezu Well, I believe I am pretty descriptive. I have adjusted my description giving more details.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 3 diffrent functions:

```
SELECT ROUND(12.51231, 2)
```

RESULT: `12.51`

```
SELECT CEILING(12.51231)
```

RESULT: `13`

```
SELECT FLOOR(12.51231)
```

RESULT: `12`

and you can use all these functions in a `case` :

```
select case when 15 < 14 then ceiling(13.5) else ceiling(12.5) end
```

RESULT: `13`

Comment: I am sorry I still don't understand what I should round. I don't have an exact number to round inside the case statement (to round as in your example). I need to round the result of calculation. You can see on the picture#2 the issue very clearly. Whenever I round OB_BILLING and RET_BILLING everything stops working and I receive an error.

Comment: @Rezu, both I and you know the answer. At least you could give it in the form of `select ceiling(case when ... else ... end)`. I'm downvoting your answer due to the lack of fellowship.

Comment: @DIFF1, what is the error you receive? Please, edit your question and state the error there, ok?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to round to 2 decimal places.

```
SELECT
ROUND(CASE WHEN .... END, 2) AS OB_BILLING,
ROUND(CASE WHEN .... END, 2) AS RET_BILLING,
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this:

```
round(
    CASE
        WHEN s.DEIO = 'O' THEN s.DERSP 
                          ELSE 0
    END,
    2
) AS OB_BILLING,
round(
    CASE 
        WHEN s.DEIO = 'I' AND 'WALMART_CONSOLIDATE' = 'N' THEN -1 * s.DERSP 
                                                          ELSE 0
    END,
    2
) AS RET_BILLING,
```